# istringstream not working when the line has been taken as input from console but working with a file

Tags: c++, string, stream, iostream

Here is a code that I am using to read an input from console. It reads the first line, using the string stream it also reads the words from that string, but just after that it crashes.

The same thing works file if instead of stdin, I take the input from a file. Then the same code works without crashing. I am unable to understand what the problem is.

```
int main()
{
    string line;

    set<string> dict;
    vector<string> file;
    vector< vector<string> > message;

    while(true)
    {
        getline(cin,line);
        if(line.at(0) == '/' && line.at(1) == '/')
            break;
        else
            dict.insert(line);
    }
    int i =0;
    istringstream stream;
    while(true)
    {   
        getline(cin,line);
        cout<<line<<endl;
        stream.str(line);
        string words;
        while(stream >> words)
        {
            message[i].push_back(words);
            cout<<words<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"Reached out of the first loop"<<endl;
        i++;
    }

    cout<<"The dictionary input is"<<endl;
    set<string>::iterator it;
    for(it = dict.begin();it!=dict.end();it++)
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    int vec_size = message.size();
    for(i = 0;i<vec_size;i++)
    {
        int inner_size = message[i].size();
        for(int j= 0;j<inner_size;j++)
            cout<<message[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am giving an input as

//dict
string1
string2
string3
//message
12345 67
xc23 bgv34
090ds 3ndlk

I want to read the the words before //message into a set of strings
and the words after //message into a 2D vector where each row contains the words that have been added in the first line

If I take this input from a file, then it works correctly, but not with input from console.

Comment: What does it say when it crashes? Also, can you please post a complete, compilable and executable example that reproduces the crash?

Comment: Please post a [short, self contained, correct](http://sscce.org/) example, not a *snippet*.

Comment: @BjörnPollex It does not say anything, the message I get is that the program has stopped working. Actually I have not used any debugger I am using just Dev C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have used ostringstream. Put in stuff into it, and finally create a std::string out of the stream which is what you want to do here.